# Get Rows contains Pattern MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have very simple table like below

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `won` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_data`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_data` (`id`, `won`, `time`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2022-10-18 05:21:37'),
(2, 2, '2022-10-18 05:21:37'),
(5, 0, '2022-10-18 05:22:02'),
(6, 2, '2022-10-18 05:22:02'),
(7, 2, '2022-10-18 05:22:18'),
(8, 1, '2022-10-18 05:22:18');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_data`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_data`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_data`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
COMMIT;
```

What I am trying to achieve is select all rows which contains pattern of won like 0,2,2
so it will select id called 5,6,7 in above example.
if my pattern is like 1,2
it should select ids called 1 and 2 like this.

Database Fiddle is here

https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=RDJuie555L

I am finding solution from last hour but not able to achieve the goal. Let me know if any expert here can help me for same.

Thanks!

Comment: *rows which contains pattern of won like 0,2,2* What ordering must be applied? `id ASC`? `time` is not safe, it contains duplicates.

Comment: Does your MySQL version is 5.x like in the fiddle, or your working version is 8+?

Comment: yes , order by id asc is fine to go with

Comment: @Akina I have mysql version 8.0 in my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id id0,
         LEAD(id) OVER w id1,
         LEAD(id,2) OVER w id2,
         CONCAT_WS(',',
                   won,
                   LEAD(won) OVER w,
                   LEAD(won,2) OVER w) won_list
  FROM tbl_data
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY id)
  )
SELECT tbl_data.*
FROM tbl_data
JOIN cte ON tbl_data.id IN (cte.id0, cte.id1, cte.id2)
WHERE cte.won_list = '0,2,2'
```

| id | won | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 2022-10-18 05:22:02 |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-10-18 05:22:02 |
| 7 | 2 | 2022-10-18 05:22:18 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TgPDP43R)

PS. If there exists more than one copy of needed pattern then the rows will mix. Add `ORDER BY id` clause to the outer query for to sort output rows and any of `cte.idN` (N=0..2) to its output list for to see separate pattern groups.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot sir. I think there some issue if my patter is with two numbers or 4 numbers its giving empty result. https://dbfiddle.uk/PVuXgmGh Thanks!

Comment: @Manisha This query may test 3-rows patterns only. For another values amount you must edit it accordingly. https://dbfiddle.uk/XVNxTJMt

Comment: I have accepted answer as well up voted it. Thanks again sir!

Comment: I am getting duplicate id as result, can you please look in https://dbfiddle.uk/PCMc_CQr Thanks!

Comment: @Manisha You use `WHERE cte.won_list = '1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1'` - i.e. 8-rows pattern. Whereas I have said explicitly that "This query may test 3-rows patterns only".